# Trying to create a background color dependent upon audio being played simultaneously

Tags: html, audio, input, colors, background

I'm trying to see if there is a way to determine to code the background color to be dependent upon the audio currently being played, if any, or time of day, etc. Any links or helps to similar queries would be appreciated.

I've tried searching for similar questions online but haven't found anything.

Comment: Your question is too vague.  Are you trying to determine a background color based on the URL of the audio file being played, or on the actual sound played by that audio file?  In general, to convert a string (such as a URL, a timestamp, etc.) to a color, hash that string to a hash function (such as MD5 or MurmurHash), then take the first 24 bits of that string, then convert those 24 bits (made up of three 8-bit chunks) to an RGB color (made up of the three components red, green, and blue).

Comment: Yea so like if there is an audio file being played, then somehow link the input from the sound bite to a string and hash as you have stated (similar to the way concert lights change depending upon speed of song, tempo etc.) Can that all be done in html and css ? Do you have an example of a hash string I could reference?

Comment: "The input from the sound bite", so do you mean the actual pitch and tempo currently being played -- or simply the URL of the audio being played, which is trivial by comparison?  Also, is the audio, being played, within the control of the HTML page, or can it also come from an outside source, such as a music player app?  If the latter, I'm not aware of any way to analyze that audio using just HTML.  In any case, edit your question (use the "edit" link) to better state what you want to achieve (including more information on your requirements, your inputs, and your outputs).